# How to blur video background?

Tags: compositing-nodes, blur

I was wondering how to blur a video background (a person is talking and you wish to remove the background)? Should the compositor be used?

Example video that you can use for testing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zncqb-n3zMo

Example of blurred background image:

[image]

Comment: If you are rendering the video from a 3D scene (so you have Z pass depth information) you can use the *Defocus* node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [Matt's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6168/599), to blur based on a mask in the compositor:

1. Create a new mask in the UV image editor by selecting *Mask* mode and clicking new:

   [image]
2. Add a mask primitive (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and edit it to match your the part of your image you don't want to blur (or the other way around, do whatever is easier to mask because you can always invert it later) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to add more points.

   [image]
3. Once you have your mask, add it in the compositor with a *Mask node* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Input > Mask* and pick your mask from the drop down):

   [image]

   You should be able to view it by connecting it to the viewer node:

   [image]

Here are two methods for bluring based on this mask:

## Method 1

Using a *Gaussian* blur node with a variable size:

[image]

## Method 2

Using a *Fast Gaussian* blur (which doesn't support variable sizes):

[image]

I believe method 2 is a little faster (in computation speed) for large blurs, however it's a little more complex and artifact prone than method 1.

Comment: Very detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the compositor should be used. The most straightforward approach would probably be to [animate a mask](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor) which you use to selectively blur (or remove) parts of the video.